# How to Create a Dynamic Path for Grabbing Variables from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm calling many web services in Python which return JSON formatted text describing the same data, but each are structured differently. Rather than write a dozen ways to loop through the data, I'm attempting to create a common base path and common field name, but not understanding now to create a dynamic name to grab the desired field.

**service1** calls the street address, "addr1" while **service2** calls it, "address1".

**service1** JSON path to the street address: ["results"][0]["locations"][0]["addr1"] .

**service2** JSON path to the street address:  ["query"][0]["address1"] .

**service1** response:

```
{
    "results":[
        {
            "providedLocation":{
                "location":"123 Main St. Whoville"
            },
            "locations":[
                {
                "addr1":"123 Main St.",
                "city":"Whoville"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From my common terms translation.ini file

```
[service1]
base_path = '["results"][0]["locations"]' 
field     = "addr1"
[service2]
base_path = '["query"]'
field     = 'address1'
```

I'm looping through the address locations returned like this:

```
j         = json.loads(response.text)
try:
    for i in range(0,count_the_results()):
        street_number = j[base_path][i][field]  # multiple locations returned

except KeyError:
    print("street_number error again")
```

I tried using eval(), but it drops the brackets ([0]) which breaks the path

```
j[eval(base_path)]
```

I tried breaking the base_path into pieces but eval still gets me

```
base_path = '["results"][0]'
locations = '["locations"]'
j[eval(str(base_path)+str(locations))]
```

I could use keys, but still have to build the unique path somehow

> **j.get("results",{})[0].get("locations")**[i][field]

Could someone point out what I'm missing in creating the path, please?

Comment: Is there any reason you are always using the first result of each list? Both service models in your examples support having several addresses; shouldn't you code in a way that you can handle them all?

Comment: good question, Joe. The "base_path" is the part I've identified as a static part of the response - always 1 item, and it just happens to be named 'results' (plural). This is followed by an unknown list number of addresses, incremented by [i] in my example, before the desired field. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: you can always do a step through method where you look at the keys if they are a certain string. this way you only need to have the name of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
def get_item(response, path):
    for item in path:
        response = response[item]
    return response

# Assume we need the string 'qwerty'
spam = {'spam': ['eggs', {'13': 'qwerty'}], 'eggs': 123}
# Then that will be our path:
path = ['spam', 1, '13']

print get_item(spam, path)
```

It prints `'qwerty'`.

---

The shorted and more efficient (but probably less understandable) way of doing this is to use builtin `reduce` function like that:

```
def get_item(response, path):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], path, response)
```

---

The other problem is how to store the path in the `.ini` file. My suggestion would be to write it in JSON format, then pass it to json.loads(), which will get you the path like in my example.

```
base_path = '["results", 0, "locations"]'
```

You get the string `'["results", 0, "locations"]'` from your config (it might be a problem, is it?), pass it to `json.loads`

```
path = json.loads(path_string)
```

and you can use it in `get_item` function.

Comment: I'm going to test your suggestions, Ilya. I didn't think of loading values out of my own file using json so I rewrote it for configparser after hours of frustration.

Comment: @jim I'm sorry that it caused you frustration, I suggested it because I thought you could put a JSON string (and any other string) in your config easily. Did my suggestion work after you rewrote your program to use `configparser`?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I did not mean that you caused me frustration at all - it was all self-inflicted :) . Your answer is great and I'm using it test results from each web service provider. You really made my day with your suggestion and I appreciate it. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Very nice to hear that:) Really glad that I could be of any help!